# Generic types: Capture type of attribute

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

Suppose I have this codebase:

```
public class DataIn {}
public interface DataOut {}
public class DataSpecial1 implements DataOut {}
public class DataSpecial2 implements DataOut {}
public class TranslatorAndHandler<T extends DataOut>{
    public T translate(DataIn dataIn);
    public void handle(T t);
}
public class TranslatorImpl1 implements TranslatorAndHandler<DataSpecial1> {
    public DataSpecial1 translate(DataIn dataIn){
        // Some code
        return null;
    }
    public void handle(DataSpecial1 data){}
}
public class TranslatorImpl2 implements TranslatorAndHandler<DataSpecial2> {
    public DataSpecial2 translate(DataIn dataIn){
        // Some code
        return null;
    }
    public void handle(DataSpecial2 data){}
}
public class Wrapper {
    public static TranslatorAndHandler<? extends DataOut> getCorrectTAH(){
         if(someValue) {
             return new TranslatorImpl1();
         }
         return new TranslatorImpl2();
    };
    private static final TranslatorAndHandler<? extends DataOut> tah = getCorrectTAH();
    private DataOut savedData;
    public Wrapper(DataIn dataIn) {
        savedData = tah.translate(dataIn);
    }
    public void handleData() {
        tah.handle(savedData); // Compiler won't accept this line
    }
}
```

A bit of context: I write a model format (DataIn) that is read by a reader and then passed on the the Model (Wrapper). As different users will have different OpenGL-capabilites I externalized the rendering (TranslatorAndHandler). This would allow me to load the correct OpenGLHandler at runtime (getCorrectTAH()) and then make this Handler translate the read raw data into an optimized format for his own purposes.

Any human can tell that there is no problem with the code and that it is indeed typesafe. How can I remodel (redesign?) my approach so that this will work?

Currently it's showing this compiler error:

> The method handle(capture#1-of ? extends DataOut) in the type
>   TranslatorAndHandler is not applicable
>   for the arguments (DataOut)

Comment: Hi, could you be more specific with the problem you're facing in?

Comment: I added the compiler error to the question

Comment: How do you expect to declare and implement `getCorrectTAH`?

Comment: I expect to fix the compiler error, so only the class Wrapper should be touched (not `getCorrectTAH`).

Comment: That depends entirely on what `getCorrectTAH` does and returns.

Answer (score 2):

You pass an instance of type `DataOut` to `tah.handle`, however, it expects some subtype of it - for example, it should be clear that the following code should not compile:

```
interface DataOut { }
interface SomeDataOut extends DataOut { }

class TranslatorAndHandler<T extends DataOut> {
    public void handle(T t) { }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TranslatorAndHandler<SomeDataOut> tah = null;
        DataOut t = null;
        tah.handle(t);
    }
}
```

And it indeed causes a compilation error:

> incompatible types: DataOut cannot be converted to SomeDataOut

A possible fix is making `Wrapper` class generic like this:

```
public class Wrapper<T extends DataOut> {
    private final TranslatorAndHandler<T> tah = getCorrectTAH();
    private T savedData;
    public Wrapper(DataIn dataIn) {
        savedData = tah.translate(dataIn);
    }
    public void handleData() {
        tah.handle(savedData);
    }
}
```

However, in this case `tah` field can't be static, since it's not possible to refer to type parameters from static members.

Comment: it WILL be the correct type though because the field was previously return from the SAME instance (tah) that will then handle the data (tah.translate(DataIn) returns the same type tah.handle() accepts). Making Wrapper generic seems somewhat overshot since nobody on the outside needs to know/hand over the correct type T.

Comment: The type of `savedData` field in your code is `DataOut`. Compiler has no idea that it's guaranteed to be the type acceptable by `tah.handle`.

Comment: And that is basically the question. How can I make the compiler know? (Sorry for being so foggy, I just didn't know how to phrase it)

Answer (score 1):

Generics are a compile time concept in Java. With a declaration like

```
public class TranslatorAndHandler<T extends DataOut>{
```

any variable declaration (or expression) of type `TranslatorAndHandler` must (really should, don't use raw types) provide a type argument to bind to the type parameter `T`. If you provide one, you **know** what type it is and you can use it. If you provide a wildcard, you **don't know** what type it is and therefore can't use it.

Your `Wrapper` class must know what type it is handling. If, at compile time, you don't know what `getCorrectTAH()` returns, ie. it's declared like this

```
public TranslatorAndHandler<?> getCorrectTAH() {...}
```

then you cannot expect to be able to use `TranslatorAndHandler` type parameter, since it is bound to `?` which you cannot know at compile time.

It doesn't seem like `TranslatorAndHandler` should be generic in the first place. There's nothing special it can do with subtypes of `DataOut`.

Comment: Yes it can. For example an OpenGL4.0 implementation can save the data in buffers already fed to the GPU while this is not possible in for example OpenGL1.0. This is some optimizing mentioned in the question. It will improve the program's ability to adapt to different contexts. This is what `getCorrectTAH()` does. It provides an adapter for the present environment.

Comment: @WorldSEnder What is the _Yes it can_ referring to? To the wildcard? There's nothing you can know about the wildcard at compile time (except its bounds). There is also nothing you can know about it at runtime.

Comment: it's refering to the last sentence in your answer.

Comment: @WorldSEnder Aha. The `TranslatorAndHandler` class declares a type parameter with bounds `T extends DataOut`. Inside the class, all `TranslatorAndHandler` knows about `T` is that it is at least a `DataOut`. It cannot know if you use it with a `DataOutImpl` or a `SomeOtherImplDataOut`. This information can only come by querying an instance of type `T` for its type at runtime, through `getClass()` or `instanceof`. As such, in this case of a wildcard, there is no point having it be generic. If you use it elsewhere, that's a different story.

Comment: @WorldSEnder But again, we need more context about the other classes and methods involved. How is `getCorrectTAH` declared?

Comment: `public TranslatorAndHandler<? extends DataOut> getCorrectTAH();` also added that to the question itself.

Comment: @WorldSEnder Right, there's absolutely nothing you can do about `?`, it expresses that you don't know and don't care what type it is. Note that even if you could, it would still fail because `savedData` is declared as a `DataOut`, while your `handle` method expects a specific subtype. Basically, this _catch-all_ design won't work.

Answer (score 0):

By changing the wrapper class to the following one can dodge the compiler error:

```
public class Wrapper {
    // Will be casted
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static final TranslatorAndHandler<DataOut> tah =
            (TranslatorAndHandler<DataOut>) getCorrectTAH();
    private DataOut savedData;
    public Wrapper(DataIn dataIn) {
        savedData = tah.translate(dataIn);
    }
    public void handleData() {
        tah.handle(savedData); // Accepted because we can be sure that this cast will not fail
    }
}
```

As said one can be sure that this is type-safe so this way one doesn't get a compiler error.

Comment: I hope you see how pointless it is for `TranslatorAndHandler` to be generic here. You do not make use of the type parameter `T` at all. Get rid of it and replace all uses of `T` in `TranslatorAndHandler` with `DataOut`.

Comment: But I really use it in TranslatorAndHandler. Just that you know. Just because you don't see it doesn't mean it isn't there. I said I do means I do, okay? Do you see the real implementation of TranslatorAndHandler's subtypes? Because they use it.